# TypeScript - Interface. Define a property with either empty object or this object

Tags: javascript, typescript

Take for example this TypeScript code:

```
interface IBook {
    metadata: {} | {
        title: string;
        author: string
    };
}

const bookOne: IBook = {
    metadata: {}
};

const bookTwo: IBook = {
    metadata: {
        TEST: 'Red Book',
    }
};
```

As you can see, `metadata` can only be an object. But, what I'm trying to figure out, how do I make it either empty object (`{}`) or if it needs to have properties within that object to make it only `title` and `author`.

I think I know why it's wrong but I can't seem to find the either. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is OK to potentially have subsets of `metadata` then [Hitmands' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57447773/1887860) works just fine because it would allow you to have only `author`, only `title` or both.

Otherwise, if you are looking for an "all or nothing" scenario, I would go with making `metadata` optional:

```
interface IBook {
    metadata?: {
        title: string;
        author: string
    };
}
```

[TypeScript Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICED2mDWyDeAUMicgLYRhwAmcVA-AFwHGltjBgA2EzAzmCigA5gG5WbEnACuYABaYo-QSInIAvuPWFCAel3IAcpnKUadOIQSYQA5ACNsOAPIheaLLmQBeApp36yADCmGQADjyQplS0VFY2do64ACoA7pjMGE4+LGwUMRbMRJKkHNzuAETJcigAglBgyJgwyADqcFAVADRqbDLyiswVAMrSIMjJAF7SFWra2noGqCDW4ZEo+eZUyAAUoJDgwDZwXFwAnsigAG4nwNQAlPG2jUk41VAQ7llevsWkm7E4EVeqR+golMgRmMJtNZmx5gEDABZMyA5CpThydFQGzCZBhHFhaAcCB8Xb7CCHY6nC7XW4PAB0T0STgAYphpBDvnhfmoAYVciUJgBRYbJZgAcgAShBqMhPDgJT14YRNEA)

This way, you either have a complete `metadata` object or nothing.

As an alternative, you could make `metadata` possibly `undefined`:

```
interface IBook {
    metadata: undefined | {
        title: string;
        author: string
    };
}
```

However, this makes the assignment of `metadata` mandatory even when there is no data:

```
// Error. Property `metadata` is missing but required in type `IBook`.
const bookOne: IBook = {};

// Valid.
const bookTwo: IBook = {
    metadata: undefined
};
```

Comment: Oh that makes total sense. Duh. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like neither `title`, nor `author` are required properties... so better to mark them as `optional` imho.

```js
interface IBook {
  metadata: {
    title?: string;
    author?: string;
  };
}
```